# Redirect page to default subpage

Tags: pages, redirect, child-pages, customization

On a site that I'm working on I have a particular page that has four subpages, which act like process steps. I want the parent page to always redirect to the first of these as a default, should the user type in or click on a url that only points to the parent page. Is there a way to accomplish this without the use of mod_rewrite?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this.
This will check if a page has child pages and if it does then it will redirect the first page in array ordered by menu order.

```
// get child pages
$child_page = get_pages( "child_of=" . $post->ID . "&sort_column=menu_order" );

if ( $child_page ) {

    // get id of first child page
    $firstchild = $child_page[0];
    wp_redirect( get_permalink( $firstchild->ID ) );

}
```

Comment: Ah, didn't know about wp_redirect. Thanks!